# OCUnit in XCode 4, problems accessing class to test

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ocunit

I added a Cocoa Touch testing bundle to my existing iPhone application, the default test seems to run (fail!) just fine, but when I try to add my class from my project to the test target I am not able access the class from that file.

I added the file that I want to test to the unit testing target, but if I try and make an instance of the class I want to test, it is unknown.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Are you importing the app class's header file in the unit test code? If you're unit testing Objective-C code, you shouldn't have to add the app class files to the unit test target.

Comment: Well, I am pretty certain I already tried that, but that seemed to do the trick. Thanks.